# Primary Key field with merged tables

Tags: ms-access

Apologies for the noob question (I'm keenly learning as I go). I'd be grateful for some advice on the Primary Key.

I have 5 separate (unrelated) tables (Access 2003) containing similar fields that I will be merging (using Append queries) into a single new table. Each record between tables is unique (no duplicated).

Each separate table already has a primary key field using the default autonumber method (1-n). This means (I'm thinking) that there will be many duplicate primary key numbers between tables.

Is it standard practice (and ok to do) to detete the existing primary key field and create a new (autonumber; 1-n) upon merging. Should I do this before the merge (for each separate table) or after the merge (on the single new table)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your new table with the table structure, primary keys and any other necessary metadata defined.  Then run a SELECT INTO statement from each of the five table tables specifying the columns to copy into the new table.  Since you already have your identity column defined on the new table and you are not selecting the identity column on the old table(s) the data should copy over and the insert will assign a new primary key value.

Comment: Thanks Chad, that's a far better way to do this....create identity column in new table before SELECT INTO, and not selecting identity/pk field in the source tables. Many thanks.